# Spark -- custom reduce function to save to disk then upload to s3

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a job with tuples that I am doing a groupBy over, to get n partitions.

Per partition, for each tuple in the partition I would like to call a function f(tuple) that:

- calls a JNI to a C++ library that saves to a file on disk that tuple (We are building a rocksdb index)

After this is reduce step is done, the reducer should upload the file on disk to s3.

Is this possible with the spark framework?

I thought about collecting the partitions onto the driver and doing it there, but it may not be very efficient

I also thought about using a JNI library to wrap the C++. This would be to do the above. Or is the jar sent to the executors? Can you use jni functions within functions you send to the executors?

Comment: If all you need to to save the file to disk- why not use the built in functions to save to disk?

Comment: I don't just need to save the disk. Each row needs to be converted to binary and placed in a specific location in a specific file. We're building a database index segment. I was wondering if we can run jni functions on the executors